# Salary issue and employer betrayed me

Tags: communication, salary, raise

Recently, I got an offer from good and popular company. I discussed with my current employer about the offer, and he promised to increment my salary immediately. He was also a former-employee of the company that gave me the offer.

So, I rejected the offer. However, my employer has still not increased my salary, and he does not want to meet me. His manager says that he is not available for the next five days. I rejected my check, because they reduced some money on monthly check.

How can I respond to this situation? I need this money, and there are people dependent on me.

Comment: Let this be a life lesson, never take a counteroffer. You need to start looking for a new job again.

Comment: If the counter offer wasn't gven to you in writing and by someone with the authority to make the offer, I doubt there is much you can do.

Comment: Maybe contact the offer you rejected and tell them if the offer is still good you would accept.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to ask the place you rejected if their offer still stand. I mean it was only a few days ago right? So why not call them or email them and say you made an error and wish to be employed again. Don't mention anything about the situation at your current company.

Comment: Obviously you will take note how your company is willing to treat you, so we all encourage you to return the favour at the most inconvenient time for them.

Comment: Also next time before doing something make sure you consult with others in your own inner circle. If you have none like that, then you can always ask online.

Comment: He/She might have betrayed you, but your mistake was taking your employer's word instead of his/her signature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right now there is not much for you to do - wait 5 days and see if your employer is willing to discuss this.  It is possible that there was a mistake or misunderstanding.

In the future, the next time you have a job offer (and there will be a next time if you are looking) do not discuss it with your current employer.

Comment: This. Counteroffers are rarely genuine! They are typically a sign of desperation. While he certainly succeeded in screwing the OP over, this employer is still losing his employee due to this betrayal, so perhaps the purpose was never more than simply revenge. The OP should call this company up and try to get the offer reinstated.

Comment: @AndreiROM Indeed.  In most cases the only purpose they serve is to allow the employer to transition you from any critical systems and projects, remove your permissions, have you train your replacement, and then fire you.

Answer (score 4):

It should probably be important to note that one shouldn't use a offer as a way to demand a pay raise at his current employer. In most cases they'll tell you goodbye but in some cases a employer will try to counter offer someone leaving the company because they don't want to be stuck with finding a new employee. This counter offer will normally be a "promise" and should never be taken seriously. There's a high chance your employer wants to keep you in until they find a replacement then write you off. You fell for it unfortunately.

As always a counter offer should and ought to be in writing and in your hands. If you are "promised" a pay raise, then continue on with the process of leaving the company and securing a new position. Normally if an employer sees value in you, they will want to keep you on board by having a written counter offer in hand.

I'm not sure if this is your first professional job. If it is take it as a very valuable lesson. Now you may be out of a job with no offer in hand. Even if you are still employed you now have to rush to find a new job because you feel bitter and enraged at being ripped off. There's a high chance you will now take the first offer and ultimately repeat this mistake.

Whatever the case is don't feel depressed. Instead use it as a lesson and continue on with life. Nothing wrong with getting ripped off from time to time, just don't repeat it again.

Comment: I have worked for maybe 10 companies over 20+ years.  I took the counter offer once and then only because they fully met my concerns, which involved where I was living, not the work, co-workers, or salary.  Even then I only stayed about another year before something truly better came along.